# Need to reduce height of an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, jquery-mobile

This is my code

```
<div data-role="page" id="callAjaxPage">

    <img id="logo" src="images/logo.JPG" alt="logo" />

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <form id="callAjaxForm" data-ajax="false">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="userName" id="userNameLabel">Username</label> <input
                    type="text" name="userName_r" id="userName" value="" /> <label
                    for="password" id="passwordLabel">Password</label> <input
                    type="password" name="password_r" id="password" value="" /> <br />

                <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code i have an image which is the logo. **I Just need to reduce the height of the image**. What i have tried is manually setting the height to say 150px but what happens is that the height gets reduced but my width also reduces. Even if i hardcoded my width, still it reduces. The problem maybe the image is small.I also tried placing it in a div and i manually set the corresponding height and width but the div concept cuts the image. I dont want the image to be cut or something.I just want it to shrink in height. I dont care about the quality. How to do it?

Comment: Seem all three current suggestion on this issue should work. Seems you may have another issue - perhaps with CSS or perhaps with a resize with a timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reducing the height is doing what almost anyone wants - keeping the aspect-ratio when you change the height. If you need to keep the width, change the width AND the height to the height it was with the desired width

for example [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Z3hMP/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $("#logo");
  var width = img.width();
    alert(width);
  img = $('<img height="250" width="'+width+'" alt="'+img.attr("alt")+'" src="'+img.attr("src")+'"/>')
  $("#logo").replaceWith(img);
});
```

Comment: Yeah that would be le picture of me you're lulzing. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can either do this in CSS.

```
#logo {
    width: 80px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Or if you want to resize the image dynamically with javascript.

```
$("#logo").attr("width", $("#logo").width());
$("#logo").attr("height", 30);
```

Comment: Will the last one not resize twice, keeping the aspect-ratio both times?

Comment: Nah, it sets the height and width attributes on the image tag individually. Same effect as hardcoding the attributes. It will become beautifully distorted. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/TA6Qu/2/

Comment: Then I do not understand OPs issue - we need to see the code he used since yours (which I contemplated and discarded due to OPs concerns) is much simpler than mine. So +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

You can set separately width and height using the style attribute.

For example :

```
<img style="height:40px;width:300px;" src=0NfSJ.jpg>
```

Comment: I tried that.Since the image is small.The image is not expanding to the width which we give...

Comment: This is the standard way, and it works. You must have another problem. Can you put your page displaying the problem on the internet somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

You just specify the width and height attributes, and the image will be displayed in that size:

```
<img id="logo" src="images/logo.JPG" alt="logo" width="300" height="20" />
```

Here is a demo of a 5x5 image displayed as 300x20: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/A9pAP/